# How to close my popupwindow once the submit button click?

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

i create a popupwindow which open 1 of my pages from my cakephp.
This popup is a form which link to other page.
Upon u click the 'Submit' button, it wil auto save the data to Mysql and close it.

I would like to close the popup window once the click submit button.
i set top.close(); but stil no function.

What i mising..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function popup(mylink, windowname){
    if (! window.focus)return true;
        var href;
    if (typeof(mylink) == 'string')
        href=mylink;
    else
        href=mylink.href;
    window.open(href, windowname, 'width=800,height=1200,scrollbars=yes');
    return false;
    }
    </script>   
    <p><A HREF="http://.../index.php/products/add" onClick="return popup(this, 'notes');top.close();">Add Products</A></p>
```

Comment: please tag this as javascript.

Answer (score 1):

window.open() returns a reference to the new window. Then you can:

```
my_win = window.open(...);
[...]
my_win.close();
```

Comment: function popup(mylink, windowname){
  
  if (! window.focus)return true;
   var href;
  if (typeof(mylink) == 'string')
    href=mylink;
  else
      href=mylink.href;
  my_win=window.open(href, windowname, 'width=800,height=1200,scrollbars=yes');
  my_win=window.close();

  }

i try put after the window.open but n work. y?

Answer (score 0):

if the popup is the window that contains the submit button, you need.  "window.close();"  Otherwise, "var someRef=window.open();someRef.close()"

Answer (score 0):

write below line in function where form goes after submit

```
echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
```

and Remove the window.close() from the form onsubmit event

Answer (score -1):

If you're using PHP just do this; it works for me.

Just place this below the submit form.

```
<?php
$close = 1;
if ($close) {
    echo '<body onunload="self.close()">';
}
```